# How much of my 401(k) should I roll over to a Roth IRA to pay the least taxes?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, 401k, roth-ira, roth-conversion

I am 61 yrs old want and I want to start rolling over my 401K to a Roth-IRA account. How can I figure out how much money I should roll over in order to pay the least taxes? Through a google search, I was ONLY able to locate tax estimator tools, which are used for payroll deductions.

Comment: Are you still employed by the company?

Comment: The edits you made fundamentally change the question.  That is frowned upon.  Besides, googling "federal income tax brackets" is pretty quick.  A lot quicker than editing the question.

Comment: I tried to delete the post and the prompt advised against it. What is the recommended course of action at this point?

Comment: Did the prompt say *why* they recommended against deletion?

Comment: Yes, something to the effect that it prevents others to see the post when they search on the topic, so it was recommended to edit the post to improve it. I really didn't want to make matters more complicated so I didn't delete it. I have heard that StackOverflow and StackExchange typically lock you out of the account if they don't like your post, so I try to avoid that. In this case, I made an unintentional mistake so I hope the account is not locked.

Comment: @Anthony Asking for website recommendations is considered off-topic on our site, which is the reason that your original question was closed.  Also, we don't like when questions are edited after they are posted to change the topic completely.  I have reverted your question to the original text, and then edited it to remove the website recommendation request.  It now fits the answer you got.  Your question may or may not get reopened, but don't worry about your account either way.  You are not in trouble, and you will not be locked out or suspended after one (or even a few) closed questions.

Comment: Thank you Ben, for the necessary edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The money in the Roth conversion is simply treated as ordinary income.  Thus, just add it to your expected "other" incomes to get your "unadjusted" income.

After all relevant adjustments, you'll know what tax bracket you'll be in.

Thus, I'd use one of the tax estimator tools to see what my AGI would be **without a Roth conversion**, and then convert just enough so that I'll stay in that same tax bracket.

Next year, I'd perform the same exercise.

Comment: * Also need to make sure the additional income doesn't disqualify you from any tax credits.